# Как сделать блок с текстом рядом с видео чтобы было адаптивно?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.block-bg3 {
  color: #13334c;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 28px; }

.block-btn3 {
  color: #005792;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f6f6e9;
  border: 1px solid transparent; }

.block2-bg3__video {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 52%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .block2-bg3__video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }

.block3-bg3 {
  background-color: #e3f3fe;
  padding-bottom: 20px; }

.block3-bg3__span {
  color: #005792;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 31px;
  padding-left: 36px; }

.block3-bg3__span2 {
  color: #005792;
  font-family: Exo;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 36px; }

.block3-bg3__span2_btn {
  color: #fd5f00;
  font-family: "Exo - Semi Bold";
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
          border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 3px 19px; }

.block3-bg3__span2_btn2_blue {
  font-family: "Exo - Semi Bold";
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #13334c;
  padding: 3px 23px; }

.block3-bg3__span2_btn2_bgBlue {
  background-color: #b3e0ff;
  padding: 3px 28px; }
```

```html
<section class="bg2">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="block2-bg3">
     <div class="block2-bg3__video">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y421bWMelqE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
      </iframe>
     </div>
     <div class="block3-bg3">
      <span class="block3-bg3__span">
       Реклама Nike. Granny
      </span>
      <span class="block3-bg3__span2">
       Стоимость работ подобного уровня <br>
      </span>
      <span class='block3-bg3__span2_btn'>19 500 ₽</span>
      <span class="block3-bg3__span2">
       Срок исполнения
      </span>
      <span class='block3-bg3__span2_btn block3-bg3__span2_btn2_blue'>10 дней </span>
      <span class="block3-bg3__span2">
       Из чего складывается бюджет
      </span>
      <span class='block3-bg3__span2_btn block3-bg3__span2_btn2_blue block3-bg3__span2_btn2_bgBlue'>Смета</span>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

1) Когда я верстал не получилось поставить блок с текстом рядом с видео;
2) Надо сделать так когда видео будет уменьшаться блок с текстом уменьшался и выравнивался вместе с видео как так сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По первой части вопроса:

> Когда я верстал не получилось поставить блок с текстом рядом с видео.

Судя по Вашим классам, Вы используете Twitter Bootstrap. Но в примере вы ссылку на него не проставили.

Используя Bootstrap, видео должно размещаться в одном `div` с классом `col`, а всё остальное - в другом.

Посмотрите приведенный пример кода, доделайте классы, чтобы соответствовали новой структуре. Затем можно будет перейти ко второй части вопроса.

```css
.block-bg3 {
  color: #13334c;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.block-btn3 {
  color: #005792;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f6f6e9;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.block2-bg3__video {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 52%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block2-bg3__video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block3-bg3 {
  background-color: #e3f3fe;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.block3-bg3__span {
  color: #005792;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 31px;
  padding-left: 36px;
}

.block3-bg3__span2 {
  color: #005792;
  font-family: Exo;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 36px;
}

.block3-bg3__span2_btn {
  color: #fd5f00;
  font-family: "Exo - Semi Bold";
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 3px 19px;
}

.block3-bg3__span2_btn2_blue {
  font-family: "Exo - Semi Bold";
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #13334c;
  padding: 3px 23px;
}

.block3-bg3__span2_btn2_bgBlue {
  background-color: #b3e0ff;
  padding: 3px 28px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="bg2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-7">
        <div class="block2-bg3">
          <div class="block2-bg3__video">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y421bWMelqE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
      </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-sm-5">
        <div class="block3-bg3">
          <span class="block3-bg3__span">
       Реклама Nike. Granny
      </span>
          <span class="block3-bg3__span2">
       Стоимость работ подобного уровня <br>
      </span>
          <span class='block3-bg3__span2_btn'>19 500 ₽</span>
          <span class="block3-bg3__span2">
       Срок исполнения
      </span>
          <span class='block3-bg3__span2_btn block3-bg3__span2_btn2_blue'>10 дней </span>
          <span class="block3-bg3__span2">
       Из чего складывается бюджет
      </span>
          <span class='block3-bg3__span2_btn block3-bg3__span2_btn2_blue block3-bg3__span2_btn2_bgBlue'>Смета</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Сергей Нуднов спасибо, а как сделать чтобы блок с видео и блок с текстом было одинаковой высоты  и адаптивно ?

Comment: У Вас два элемента - видео и текст. Какой из них будет определять высоту? И почему она может меняться? Как бы Вы хотели адаптировать высоту блока текста? Уменьшать шрифт? Убирать часть данных? До каких пределов? Тут масса неизвестных, поэтому я и не пытался отвечать на вторую часть. В общем случае, почитайте про CSS media запросы, например [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: @Сергей Нуднов спасибо 1) Текст 2) На разных разрешениях видео меняется, а текст нет хотелось бы чтобы было одинаково 3) Нет лучше Вы скажите как лучше ? 4) Моя проблема решается через css медиа ?

Comment: Да, вам нужно использовать CSS media или подгонять размеры Javascript'ом. Javascript позволяет иметь как угодно сложную логику. CSS media - позволяет определить верстку для ограниченного набора разрешений. Раз у Вас на разных разрешениях меняется размер видео, то от этого и нужно исходить. Высота текста зависит от высоты видео. Значит, надо уменьшать шрифт. Если при этом текст станет нечитаем, то придется убирать часть текста

Comment: @Сергей Нуднов  спасибо, итог проблема решается через media или через JS ?

Comment: Начните с CSS media. Я добавлю пример в ответ, но чуть попозже - спать пора, 1 ночи на дворе...

Comment: @Сергей Нуднов спасибо, я Вас понял